# Entering an very large integer results in a rounded number node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code

`console.log(791991727573303311)`

Expected result
`791991727573303311`

Actual result`791991727573303300`

**How do i solve this issue without resorting to using strings.**

And

***Does this only affect printing the values?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're going over the Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant.
Which is basically the limit to which a Number is accurate, anything above that and javascript will start to round the number as in your example.

To solve this you can use BigInt which supports any size of number.

Additional information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt